# Autentificación con Azure Active Directory en múltiples directorios, asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

Hola estoy intentando validar un usuario con Azure Active Directory, el directorio  y la aplicación quiero que sean dinámicas, es decir que no sea necesario declarar en el startup.Auth.cs el valor de ClientId, AADInstance, Tenant y PostLogoutRedirectUri, los quiero declarar justo cuando el usuario accede a la aplicación ya que dependiendo de la URL desde cual accede es el directorio donde se validara el usuario.

Actualización.

las configuraciones que quiere invocar cuando el cliente accede a la aplicación es la siguiente:

```
public partial class Startup{    
public static void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
            {
                app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

                app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

                app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
                    new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                    {
                        ClientId = clientId,
                        Authority = authority,
                        PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
                        Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                        {
                            AuthenticationFailed = context =>
                            {
                                context.HandleResponse();
                                context.Response.Redirect("/Error?message=" + context.Exception.Message);
                                return Task.FromResult(0);
                            }
                        }
                    });
            }
}
```

esta método quiero invocarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
   public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{

    protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {          
        var host = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host;
        Session["client_identifier"] = host;
        MuralTactil.MuralMedHost.MuralMedHost mmh = new MuralTactil.MuralMedHost.MuralMedHost();

        MM_HOST h = mmh.ReadData(host);
        if (h != null)
        {
            string name_host = string.Empty;

            if (Session["_MMHost"] != null)
            {
                name_host = AccessCore.Authorization.AcSessionAuthorize.Name;
                if (h.NAME != name_host)
                {
                    h.HostMessage = "Error: Host Connection";
                    AccessCore.Web.SecurySessionHost.Create(h, "ErrorClientConnection");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                AccessCore.Web.SecurySessionHost.Create(h, "_MMHost");
            }               
        }

        try
        {
            Startup.ConfigureAuth();
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException inv)
        {
            if (!inv.Message.StartsWith("The \"WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection\" method can be called only once."))
            {

                throw;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Cuando he intentado invocarlo no he podido obtener la referencia `IAppBuilder app`, también por lo que entiendo si hago un set a las configuración a `app`, estos cambios se aplicaran a toda a la aplicación, es decir le afectara a todos los clientes, yo quiero aplicar estas configuración por cliente, sin afectar a los demás, ya que puede pertenecer a diferente directorio dependido de la url de cual acceden.

Comment: saludos Pablo, bienvenido al sitio :D cuéntanos, qué has intentado?

Comment: Hola, intente llamar las configuraciones dentro del la clase `public class MvcApplication` en el método `protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)` pero la variable (IAppBuilder app) que se utiliza para declarar las configuraciones del para la autentificación ya no existe, al parecer estas configuraciones son para toda la aplicación y se declarar al ejecutarla, lo que yo quiero es poder cambiar las configuraciones por cliente.